# Not able to execute batch file from C++ Windows service

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to execute a batch file from my C++ Windows service. This batch file is just creating an empty file using `echo. 2>EmptyFile.txt`.

My service code looks like this:

```
        PROCESS_INFORMATION procHandles;
        STARTUPINFOA startWinInfo;
        BOOL    result;

        char * cmdname = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
        char * cmdargs = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\MyBatFile.bat";

        DWORD    procFlags;
        DWORD    waitStatus = 0;
        DWORD    procStatus = 0;
        DWORD    winErrCode;
        DWORD    inloop = 1;

        memset(&startWinInfo, 0, sizeof(startWinInfo));
        startWinInfo.cb = sizeof(startWinInfo);
        startWinInfo.lpTitle = "Slaved Console";

        procFlags = (CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE |
            CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP);

        procHandles.hProcess = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        procHandles.hThread = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        procHandles.dwProcessId = 0;
        procHandles.dwThreadId = 0;

        result = CreateProcessA(
            cmdname, cmdargs, NULL, NULL, 0, procFlags, NULL,
            NULL, &startWinInfo, &procHandles);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            winErrCode = GetLastError();
            exit(255);        // error with CreateProcessA()
        }


        waitStatus = WaitForInputIdle(procHandles.hProcess, 6000);
        inloop = GetExitCodeProcess(procHandles.hProcess, &procStatus);

        while (procStatus == STILL_ACTIVE && inloop)
        {
            waitStatus = WaitForSingleObject(procHandles.hProcess, 30000);
            if (waitStatus == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
            {
                inloop = 1;
            }
            else if (waitStatus == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {
                inloop = GetExitCodeProcess(procHandles.hProcess, &procStatus);
            }
            else
            {
                inloop = 0;    // some type of wait abandon or error ...
                exit(254);
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(procHandles.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(procHandles.hThread);

        exit(procStatus);
```

It keeps giving me `WAIT_TIMEOUT` and not executing the batch file. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: for what you call `WaitForInputIdle` ? (in console app)

Comment: and process exit when `WaitForSingleObject(procHandles.hProcess, *)` return `WAIT_OBJECT_0`. you not need call `GetExitCodeProcess`. even after process exit - exit code can be `STILL_ACTIVE`

Comment: Please don't use hard coded path

Comment: but main your error in cmd line - it mast be `"cmd /c "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\MyBatFile.bat"`;

Comment: @RbMm I tried this cmd line as well but it is not working. The process simply exits but seems my batch file is not being executed.

Comment: no, this is work ok. also many another errors in your logic and excess code

Comment: These questions are quite tedious. What you need is to learn to debug. Stop guessing, trying stuff at random. Seek to learn how to debug.

Answer (score 0):

- if we want execute bat file in cmd and exit need use `/C` switch in
  command line which *Carries out the command specified by string and
  then terminates*.
- the path of bat file in general must be enclosed in `""` in case
  exist spaces in path;
- we not need call `WaitForInputIdle` at all. especially for not gui
  process. if you check result of this call - you can note that it fail
  with error `ERROR_NOT_GUI_PROCESS`
- for wait (and are need wait ?) process termination - necessary and
  sufficient wait for process handle. not need call
  `GetExitCodeProcess` and compare it exit code with `STILL_ACTIVE`.
  and not need any loops here also
- not need zero init `PROCESS_INFORMATION` - this is out only parameter
- need not hard-code path to *cmd.exe* but get it in run-time, by query
  `ComSpec` environment variable
- always much better use **W** api instead **A**

simply code for execute bat file can look like

```
ULONG cfd(PCWSTR BatFileName)
{
    WCHAR ApplicationName[MAX_PATH];
    if (!GetEnvironmentVariable(L"comspec", ApplicationName, RTL_NUMBER_OF(ApplicationName)))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    SIZE_T cch = wcslen(BatFileName);

    PWSTR CommandLine = (PWSTR)alloca(cch * sizeof(WCHAR) + sizeof(L"/c \"\""));

    swprintf(CommandLine, L"/c \"%s\"", BatFileName);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION procHandles;
    STARTUPINFO startWinInfo = { sizeof(startWinInfo) };

    if (CreateProcess(ApplicationName, CommandLine, NULL, NULL, 0, 
        CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE |
        CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, NULL,
        NULL, &startWinInfo, &procHandles))
    {
        CloseHandle(procHandles.hThread);

        switch ( WaitForSingleObject(procHandles.hProcess, 3000))
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            break;
        default:
            TerminateProcess(procHandles.hProcess, 0); 
        }
        CloseHandle(procHandles.hProcess);

        return 0;
    }

    return GetLastError();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, `WaitForSingleObject` returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0` but still my batch file is not being executed. I am not able to identify the reason. I also tried `system` and _popen but in every case batch file is not being executed.

Comment: @Jinul why you decide that your file not being executed ? and no any sense use system and _popen because internally it anyway call `CreateProcess`

Comment: I am creating one empty file with the help of batch file, but the new file is not being created after executing this program. So I assume that batch file is not being executed.

Comment: @Jinul and in which folder you look this file ?? if you want that it will be created at the concrete folder - set it in create process. you wrong identify. bat file executed ok

Comment: I got it, Thanks for your help @RbMm.